# How to fuzzy search existing methods in a file

Tags: fzf, plugin-tagbar

I currently use tagbar to list all the methods in my php files. However I have to do several steps in order to navigate to a specific method in the file like so:
[image]

1. run the keyboard shortcut to display tagbar (`F8`)
2. jump from the left pane to the right <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
3. search for the said method name or navigate to it using the keyboard

I would like to simply hit a keyboard shortcut, and i would be able to simply fuzzy search the methods in the *existing* file and jump to it, similar to how the [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) vim plugin lets you fuzzy search files:

[image]

Comment: fzf has `:Tags` you can try

Comment: not sure how to run that from the command line? `:fzf tags` or `:fzg :tags`? neither worked

Comment: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim `:Tags` or `:BTags` commands

Comment: the `:Tags` works perfectly, but when I run `:BTags` I get this ugly error `Error running cat '/var/folders/1b/3wwzdg214cz57k2nccl_9d5c0000gn/T/vxOBh5q/14'|'/Users/abdullah/.vim/bundle/fzf/bin/fzf'  '--layout=reverse-list' '
-m' '-d' '\t' '--with-nth' '1,4..' '-n' '1' '--prompt' 'BTags> ' '--query' '' --expect=ctrl-v,ctrl-x,ctrl-t --height=10 > /var/folders/1b/3wwzdg214c
z57k2nccl_9d5c0000gn/T/vxOBh5q/13`

how do i debug such a thing?

Comment: when i run that same command from the CLI, it says: `cat: /var/folders/1b/3wwzdg214cz57k2nccl_9d5c0000gn/T/vxOBh5q/14: No such file or directory` I imagine fzf should take care of creating that directory right?

Comment: You better ask fzf issue tracker for this :)

Comment: done :) https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1172

Comment: @MaximKim i basically answered my own question here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27981/filetype-plugin-indent-on-is-blowing-up-my-vim/27986#27986, if you like you can post an answer for this question and i'll give you the right answer award!

Comment: I have just added selection of a buffer tags to my plugin, see in action: https://github.com/habamax/vim-select-more/blob/master/showcase.adoc#select-buffer-tag

Comment: Wow good stuff!!