# filetype plugin indent on is blowing up my vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype, fzf

I have the following [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/abbood/0dbb25bfdb1b9e14ac2bb4b40fb8548d).

I noticed that there is a single line that's blowing up my usage of the FZF `:BTags` command:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Ie when I run the command `:BTags` I get this error

```
Error running cat '/var/folders/1b/3wwzdg214cz57k2nccl_9d5c0000gn/T/vxOBh5q/14'|'/Users/abdullah/.vim/bundle/fzf/bin/fzf'  '--layout=reverse-list' '
-m' '-d' '\t' '--with-nth' '1,4..' '-n' '1' '--prompt' 'BTags> ' '--query' '' --expect=ctrl-v,ctrl-x,ctrl-t --height=10 > /var/folders/1b/3wwzdg214c
z57k2nccl_9d5c0000gn/T/vxOBh5q/13
```

However if I remove it, the `:Btags` command works but all my syntax highlighting is gone. What do I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "blowing up my usage"? What exactly happens when you do `:BTags`?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: that line has to come *after* the vundle stuff

Comment: @D.BenKnoble i put it after, i still get that error

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using neovim instead of vim. Neovim gave me a better error message:

```
unkown option: --layout=reverse-list
```

[image]

from there i realized that I was using an outdated version of fzf, and neovim updated and problem solved!